# opening browser in onpostexecute()

Tags: android, url, browser, android-asynctask

I want to open my browser within onpostexecute from an asynctask. But I get a nullpointerexception when starting my activity:

My code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Details");

        ScrollView scrollview = new ScrollView(context);
        LinearLayout lila1= new LinearLayout(context);
        lila1.setOrientation(1); //1 is for vertical orientation;

        lila1.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
        scrollview.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);

            final Button adv1 = new Button(context);
            adv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://androidbook.blogspot.com/");
                 Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(launchBrowser); //<- does not work

                }
            });
            lila1.addView(adv1);
```

Comment: Where are you getting a NPE?

Comment: startActivity(launchBrowser);

Comment: So launchBrowser is null, which means that either somehow you have created some variable that is interfering with Intent.ACTION_VIEW (very unlikely) or your uri parse is returning null making uriUrl null. Throw in some breakpoints or log or something and see what those values are before you try to start your activity.

Comment: both is fine...
probably it's because context or view are wrong (I'm starting it in an asynctask)...
but I don't get the solution

Comment: What type of class is the AsyncTask in? (eg Service, Activity, etc.)

Comment: You are not opening a browser in onPostExecute of anAsyncTask. What you do there is installing an on click listener. The task has long ended when the user clicks a view. And then the browser wil be started.

Comment: it's a class like this: "public class abd extends listactivity" and this class then calls the class "xyz extends AsyncTask"...

Comment: the browser does not start because I get a nullpointer exception